# Denoting multiple suspensions in figured bass Roman numeral analysis

Tags: roman-numerals, figured-bass, nonchord-tones

When composing a figured bass Roman numeral analysis for a chord that has more than one suspension, is it typical to denote both suspensions, as I have done at the end of my analysis?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've done this exactly correctly!

You can even take this one step further by showing, for instance, that the `4-3` also then moves to `♭3`.

And the same will apply to the next measure as well. One interpretation of this is to view it as a V chord with a 6 and a 4 held above it (albeit as passing notes, not as suspensions), in which case you could use a `6-5` and `4-3` (and even an `8-7`!) along with the V.

But as I said, that's only one interpretation of that next-to-last measure. Another one is similar to what you did in m. 4 with the I64 moving to V.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Also, thanks for the clarification on the cadential 64 as well. Very interesting stuff.